# modify and resize ionic popup

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

How can I following Ionic popup (first image) modify so that it looks like the second image? Can I add more input fields and resize the popup? The purpose is to create an entry by typing some information on a server like in second image. An extra page or a new form shouldn't be opened. Especially on the same page should be created an entry by using the pop-up.

**first image**

[image: first image]

**second image**

[image: second image]

**Code of first popup:**

```
myApp.controller('showPopupCtrl',function($scope, $ionicPopup) {
    // Triggered on a button click, or some other target
    $scope.showPopup = function() {
        $scope.data = {}        
        // An elaborate, custom popup
        var myPopup = $ionicPopup.show({
            template: '<input type="password" ng-model="data.wifi">',
            title: 'Enter Wi-Fi Password',
            subTitle: 'Please use normal things',
            scope: $scope,
            buttons: [
                { text: 'Cancel' },
                {
                    text: '<b>Save</b>',
                    type: 'button-positive',
                    onTap: function(e) {
                        if (!$scope.data.wifi) {
                            //don't allow the user to close unless he enters wifi password
                            e.preventDefault();
                            } else {
                            return $scope.data.wifi;
                        }
                    }
                },
            ]
        });
        myPopup.then(function(res) {
            console.log('Tapped!', res);
        });
        $timeout(function() {
            myPopup.close(); //close the popup after 3 seconds for some reason
        });
    };
});
```

Comment: at this size it will cover  whole device screen. then what is purpose of using popup ?

Comment: I have revised the question. Please see the question again. I hope it is understandable.

Comment: Use modal for this purpose. Popover are not meant for these. Link to ionic modals : http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicModal/

Answer (score 1):

you can use ionic modal for this purpose checkout this link for a documentation

http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicModal/

and you can find alot of examples in codepen